# unable to install devstack on rhel 7

Tags: openstack

On RHEL 7 when I try to install devstack I get the following error.

```
+tools/install_pip.sh:install_get_pip:79   sudo -H -E python /opt/stack/devstack/files/get-pip.py -c /opt/stack/devstack/tools/cap-pip.txt
Collecting pip!=8 (from -c /opt/stack/devstack/tools/cap-pip.txt (line 1))
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:765) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip!=8 (from -c /opt/stack/devstack/tools/cap-pip.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip!=8 (from -c /opt/stack/devstack/tools/cap-pip.txt (line 1))
++./stack.sh:main:717                       err_trap
++./stack.sh:err_trap:504                   local r=1
++./stack.sh:err_trap:505                   set +o xtrace
stack.sh failed
Error on exit
```

I tired to search around with the error but couldn't find anything. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Make sure your system is up to date.

Comment: I did  run `yum update` before running `stack.sh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the certificate is valid https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/ this would point to your firewall, it is doing ssl inspection, please visit the site in a browser, if the certificate is no issued to python.org from digicert then you are actually using an SSL certificate on your firewall, either ask you network admin to make an exemption for python.org - or - ask him to use a root CA certificate, (likely it's a local CA and all the clients on the network trust it), you other option would be to remove all of the references to https in stack.sh and it's requirements files - I don't recommend this.

Comment: The issue seems to be with the proxy. After I added the --cert argument with a valid certificate to the pip command things started working as expected.